# D365FO Tile count on workspace doesn't work

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

Situation is next one: 
I created several tiles. Every tile need to show count of records. 
Tile "Expired Active Contracts" always shows zero. 
There is created simple query with data source table Contract. Ranges are added (ContractStatus; Value: 2) and (ValidTo; Value: (LessThanDate(0)) )

When it's clicked on tile, it opens valid form with valid record, where contracts status is active (2) and ValidTo are any date before today's date, but count doesn't working.

Tried to recreate, tried several things but definitely nothing. ValidTo field is date field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some time ago I had a mistake very similar to yours in my dev environment, this steps help me to fix the error.

- 1 - Clear Usages Data.
- 2 - SysAdmin/Setup/Data cache/Tile data cache configuration. Select
  the tiles which are running into this issue and then delete the
  selected tiles.
- 3-  In VS rebuilt and Synchronized the Solution.
- 4 - Finally refresh the Application browser.

Another thing is that a while ago there was a problem for tiles refresh

> Issue 243278 Workspace tile does not update correctly when reusing the
>   same name

https://fix.lcs.dynamics.com/Issue/Details?bugId=243278&dbType=3&qc=68b6dc6804c9cea218daa102968c7acfcdfe6a990e80e0b5ec66b920a680fceb

I hope you find it useful

Comment: Tried. But still it's not working. It's like LessThanDate() method doesn't work correctly. When I remove this range, it shows correct number of active contracts.

Comment: You have lessThanDate(0) int AOT query for field ValidTo? Can you change this and put this range by code in a method of that query? or check CustOpenInvoicesPastDueListPage query in due date range

Comment: Created view, pulled data from view, and everything works. Thanks.